# JavaScript Struct Element Name From Variable - How to change?

Tags: javascript

I have a struct with some ID's generated from a ColdFusion loop that are from my database, and I have filled the struct with the ID's, setting their values to 0. I then want to be able to modify the values of each struct element **without** emptying the whole struct altogether.

I've got this at the moment, but `contactID` is the variable passed for the ID, but JavaScript thinks it's the struct element's name...

```
chatWindows.contactID = 1;
```

Here's what my struct looks like **(from Google Chrome's console)**:

```
Object {635: 0, 637: 0}
```

Here's what I want it to look like **(providing contactID = 635)**

```
Object {635: 1, 637: 0}
```

Any suggestions on how I can tell JavaScript that I'm using a variable not a literal?

Comment: Presuming somewhere earlier you have `contactID = 635`, you can use square bracket notation: `chatWindows[contactID] = 1`. But I might not have understood the question.

Comment: Yeah that's what I used, which sort of worked, only it emptied the rest of the struct element, so it turned out as: `{635: 1}` not `{635: 1, 637: 0}`

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. The `chatWindows[contactID] = 1` worked, only I missed a part of a script that emptied it. All sorted now, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I fixed it. The `chatWindows[contactID] = 1` worked, only I missed a part of a script that emptied it.